# licode publishing licode stream not working

Tags: licode

I am developing a video conference application using licode having multiple users(suppose 4).

I want that every user can view his webcam's video but he can publish his video in conference room only when he gets the permission.

I get access of camera using following.

```
localStream.init();
localStream.show("myVideo");
```

this is working fine.

Through a script we decide which user will get permission of publishing stream, under the script i am using following code to publish users stream.

```
room.publish(localStream);
```

but through this users stream is not publishing under the room, please tell me what i am doing wrong.

also is there any process to check how many streams in the room??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The localStream is always available and can be used to publish anytime. Just recheck your code again. I would suggest to use setTimeout and publish the stream after 30 seconds your localstream is generated. I am sure this will work.